# Get Local pickup plus details from the order in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, shipping-method

In Woocommerce, I just want to get "local pickup" shipping details to display on a custom email. I tried below functions but they don't show anything for "local pickup".

Which function I can use to get "local pickup" info?

I tried without success the following `WC_Order` methods:

- `$order->get_shipping_address_1()`
- `$order->get_formatted_shipping_address()`

---

**Edit:**

Sorry I did not mention that, but I am using [Local Pickup Plus](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/local-pickup-plus/) plugin

---

**Edit 2:**

This is how I got local pickup info for Local Pickups Plus Plugin docs.woocommerce.com/document/local-pickup-plus  which puts meta data to main order variable.

```
$order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

foreach ($order->get_data() as $key => $value):
        if ($key==='shipping_lines'):
            foreach ($value as $k=>$v):
                $a = $v->get_meta_data();
                foreach ($a as $x=>$y):
                    $t = $y->get_data();
                    $mykey = $t['key'] ;
                    $pickup["$mykey"] = $t['value'];
                endforeach;
            endforeach;
        endif;
endforeach;
```

Then you can use the variables below:

```
$pickup['_pickup_location_name']
$pickup['_pickup_location_address']['address_1']
$pickup['_pickup_location_phone']['address_2']
$pickup['_pickup_location_address']['postcode']
$pickup['_pickup_location_address']['city']
$pickup['_pickup_location_address']['state'] $pickup['_pickup_location_address']['country']
$pickup['_pickup_location_phone']
$pickup['_pickup_date']
$pickup['_pickup_minimum_hours']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Order items shipping details refer to: *"[Get orders shipping method details in WooCommerce 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46102428/get-orders-shipping-method-details-in-woocommerce-3/46106700#46106700)"*

To target order shipping lines details from the `WC_Order` object you can use the following code:

```
// Loop though order items shipping
foreach( $order->get_shipping_methods() as $item_id => $item ){
    $shipping_item_name          = $item->get_name();
    $shipping_item_type          = $item->get_type();
    $shipping_method_title       = $item->get_method_title();
    $shipping_method_id          = $item->get_method_id();
    $shipping_method_instance_id = $item->get_instance_id();
    $shipping_method_total       = $item->get_total();
    $shipping_method_total_tax   = $item->get_total_tax();
    $shipping_method_taxes       = $item->get_taxes();

    // Get custom meta-data
    $formatted_meta_data = $item->get_formatted_meta_data( ' ', true );

    // Displaying the row custom meta data Objects (just for testing)
    echo '<pre>'; print_r($formatted_meta_data); echo '</pre>';
}
```

> **Regarding the custom shipping metadata:**
>
> You can access it using the `WC_Data` method `get_meta()` from the custom meta **"`key`"** located in any custom meta data Objects, like:
>
> ```
> $value = $item->get_meta('the_custom_key'); // 'the_custom_key' need to be replaced by the meta "key".
> ```

---

**Note:** In most Woocommerce **email templates** and **email notification related hooks**, you can use the `WC_Order` object as it's globally included. If not you can get it from the Order ID like:

```
$order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
```

Orders related threads:

- [Get orders shipping method details in WooCommerce 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46102428/get-orders-shipping-method-details-in-woocommerce-3/46106700#46106700)
- [Get Order items and WC_Order_Item_Product in Woocommerce 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45706007/get-order-items-and-wc-order-item-product-in-woocommerce-3)
- [How to get WooCommerce order details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39401393/how-to-get-woocommerce-order-details)

---

**Addition - For Local Pickup Plus plugin**

It seems that you are using [Local Pickup Plus plugin](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/local-pickup-plus/) which adds specific custom meta data in the shipping lines.

```
// Loop though order items shipping
foreach( $order->get_shipping_methods() as $item_id => $item ){
    $location_id        = $item->get_meta('_pickup_location_id');
    $location_name      = $item->get_meta('_pickup_location_name');

    $location_address   = $item->get_meta('_pickup_location_address'); // Array
    $location_address_1 = $location_address['address_1'];
    $location_address_2 = $location_address['address_2'];
    $location_postcode  = $location_address['postcode'];
    $location_city      = $location_address['city'];
    $location_state     = $location_address['state'];
    $location_country   = $location_address['country'];

    $location_phone     = $item->get_meta('_pickup_location_phone');

    $pickup_date        = $item->get_meta('_pickup_date');
    $pickup_min_hours   = $item->get_meta('_pickup_minimum_hours');
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. I need pickup location address, phone ,notes, items to  pickup variables. Those info already shown on admin email, but we want to send custom email for a custom category products.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It's woocommerce official plugin but I could not find basic usage examples for php. It rather has user level explanations settings. https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/local-pickup-plus/

Comment: I thought it is default additional plugin, but it seems not. Sorry.

Comment: It is not on item meta data. It's on order. Is there a shortcut for this or should I try to get it from order array? 'meta_data' => 
      array (
        0 => 
        WC_Meta_Data::__set_state(array(
           'current_data' => 
          array (
            'id' => 2768,
            'key' => '_pickup_location_id',
            'value' => '7254',
          ),
           'data' => 
          array (
            'id' => 2768,
            'key' => '_pickup_location_id',
            'value' => '7254',
          ),
        ' ...

Comment: I updated the answer for the specific plugin I mentioned above.