# Display ALL available shipping methods for each specific order on admin edit order pages in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, shipping-method

On the checkout page of my WooCommerce based site, users will have a list of shipping methods to choose from depending on what they are purchasing

**This is the list I want to capture:**

[image: This is the list I want to capture]

---

Things like

- “Free Shipping” for orders over a certain price
- “Freight Shipping” for certain items, and so on.

**My goal, is to display ALL available methods for each specific order**, and display it on the “Edit Order / Order Details” page in the Admin view.

A small feature that would help us be able to quickly identify what option people are choosing more often, depending on the choices that they have available.

This is what I have so far:

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'save_available_shipping_methods' );
 
function save_available_shipping_methods( $order_id ) {
    $shippingmethods = WC()->cart->get_shipping_methods();
    update_post_meta( $order_id, '_shipping_methods', $shippingmethods );
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_shipping_address', 'get_available_shipping_methods', 10, 1 );

function get_available_shipping_methods($order){
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    if ( $order ) {
        echo '<p><strong>'.__('Available Shipping Methods: ').'</strong> ' . get_post_meta($order->get_shipping_methods(), '_shipping_field_value', true ) . '</p>';
    }
}
```

---

I'll attach a picture as well to maybe make things a little easier to follow.

**This is where I would like to put it. The current hook places the field underneath the shipping address**

[image: This is where I would like to put it. The current hook places the field underneath the shipping address]

Comment: `$order` already contains all the information you need, see [Get orders shipping items details in WooCommerce 3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46106700/11987538). so the `woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_shipping_address` hook is sufficient, there is no need to use `update_post_meta`

Comment: Now that I have re-read your question, is it the intention to display the chosen shipping method by the customer? or would you like to list **ALL** available shipping methods for that specific order?

Comment: I am wanting to display ALL available methods for each specific order

Comment: [Link To Related Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62819259/iterate-through-two-foreach-loops-at-once)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- In the `woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta` hook, the available shipping packages are stored via `update_post_meta`
- Comments with explanation added in the code

```php
function action_woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta( $order_id ) {
    // Get shipping packages
    $packages = WC()->shipping()->get_packages();
    
    // Set array
    $rate_labels = array();
    
    // Loop trough packages
    foreach ( $packages as $key => $package ) {
        // Loop through package rates
        foreach( $package['rates'] as $rate_id => $rate ) {
            // Push to array
            $rate_labels[] = $rate->get_label();
        }
    }

    // NOT empty
    if ( ! empty ( $rate_labels ) ) {
        // Update post meta
        update_post_meta( $order_id, '_available_shipping_methods', $rate_labels );
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'action_woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 10, 1 ); 

// Display on the order edit page (backend)
function action_woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_shipping_address( $order ) {
    // Get meta
    $rate_labels = $order->get_meta( '_available_shipping_methods' );
    
    // True
    if ( $rate_labels ) {
        // Loop trough rate labels
        foreach( $rate_labels as $rate_label ) {
            // Output
            echo '<p>' . $rate_label . '</p>';
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_shipping_address', 'action_woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_shipping_address', 10, 1 );
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks a bunch! Now id like to see if I could add the prices that we quoted each method for. Any suggestions on that?

Comment: Yes, in the foreach 'loop through package rates' you could use something like `$rate_cost = $rate->get_cost();`.  See [Class WC_Shipping_Rate](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Shipping_Rate.html). - Get started and if you don't get there, feel free to ask a new question, with a possible reference to this question Regards

Comment: Appreciate the help. Thanks!

Comment: So ive added references to the costs in the foreach loop, the update_post_meta function,  and echo, and it seems to only return 0.00 across the board. Am I missing a piece? Thanks again.

Comment: Just to test this without taking other factors into account, what if you replace `$rate_labels[] = $rate->get_label();` with `$rate_labels[] = $rate->get_cost();` in my answer. What do you get as a result?

Comment: ok, then it's just a matter of adding this cost to an array. Can be done via a multiarray, 2 arrays, concatenating the values ​​as a string in the already existing array,... as you can see, the prices are processed correctly. As I mentioned before, if you cannot find a solution, do not hesitate to open a new question. Regards

Comment: Ive posted a more revised question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62819259/iterate-through-two-foreach-loops-at-once . Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone is wondering, this is the final result. It will loop through each order to find the available shipping methods at the time, along with how much it was quoted for.

```
 // Capture the available shipping methods, and costs: 
      function action_woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta( $order_id ) {
      // Get shipping packages
         $packages = WC()->shipping()->get_packages();
        
    // Set array
    $rate_labels = array();
    $rate_costs = array();
    
    // Loop trough packages
    foreach ( $packages as $key => $package ) {
        // Loop through package rates
        foreach( $package['rates'] as $rate_id => $rate ) {
            // Push to array
            $rate_labels[] = $rate->get_label();
            $rate_costs[] = $rate->get_cost();
        }
    }

    // NOT empty
    if ( ! empty ( $rate_labels ) ) {
        // Update post meta
        update_post_meta( $order_id, '_available_shipping_methods', $rate_labels );
        update_post_meta( $order_id, '_available_shipping_method_cost', $rate_costs );
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'action_woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 10, 1 ); 

// Make it display on the edit order page:
function action_woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_shipping_address( $order ) {
    // Get meta
    $rate_labels = $order->get_meta( '_available_shipping_methods' );
    $rate_costs = $order->get_meta( '_available_shipping_method_cost' );
    
    $methods = array ( $rate_labels, $rate_costs );
    
    // True
    if ( $rate_labels ) {
        // Loop
        echo '<p><strong>Shipping Methods: </strong>';
        foreach(array_combine($rate_labels, $rate_costs) as $rate_label => $rate_cost) {
             echo '<p>' . $rate_label . ' - $' . $rate_cost . '</p>';
        }
    }
    
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_shipping_address', 'action_woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_shipping_address', 10, 1 );
```