# WooCommerce add custom email content based on payment method, shipping method and shipping country

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, email-notifications

I would like to have a custom text e-mail sent to the customer according to the shipping they choose. we use shipping zones.

1. Estonia - "Local pickup" - "custom_text_1" on order completed.
2. Estonia - any other shipping method - current e-mail text remains as is.
3. Anywhere outside Estonia but not "Flat rate" - "custom_text_2" on order completed.
4. Any "Flat rate" type shipping - "custom_text_3" on order completed.

I believe it's called "Flat rate" or "Fixed rate" method by default? https://prnt.sc/FyDXD6NbMkSc

I've come across [WooCommerce add custom email content based on payment method and shipping method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44885575/woocommerce-add-custom-email-content-based-on-payment-method-and-shipping-method/44886437#44886437) answer thread.

Here is my code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_order_details', 'my_completed_order_email_instructions', 10, 4 );
function my_completed_order_email_instructions( $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email ) {
    // Only for completed email notifications to customer
    if( 'customer_completed_order' != $email->id ) return;

    foreach( $order->get_items('shipping') as $shipping_item ){
        $shipping_rate_id = $shipping_item->get_method_id();
        $method_array = explode(':', $shipping_rate_id );
        $shipping_method_id = reset($method_array);
        // Display a custom text for local pickup shipping method only
        if( 'local_pickup' == $shipping_method_id ){
            echo '<p><strong>Ritiro in sede</strong></p>';
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

But this covers local shipping only.

Comment: Quick research suggests that `$order->shipping_country` should be able to get you the country, so what's left would be just writing the correct if/else logic then.

Comment: @CBroe For the country it's `$order->get_shipping_country()` as since Woocommerce 3, WC_Order properties are not anymore accessible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following instead:

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_order_details', 'completed_order_email_custom_instructions', 10, 4 );
function completed_order_email_custom_instructions( $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email ) {
    // Only for "Customer Completed Order" email notification
    if( 'customer_completed_order' !== $email->id ) return;

    if ( $order->get_shipping_country() === 'EE' && $order->has_shipping_method('local_pickup') ){
        echo '<p><strong>'.__('Ritiro in sede').'</strong></p>';
    } elseif ( $order->get_shipping_country() !== 'EE' && ! $order->has_shipping_method('flat_rate') ){
        echo '<p><strong>'.__('custom text 2').'</strong></p>';
    } elseif ( $order->has_shipping_method('flat_rate') ){
        echo '<p><strong>'.__('custom text 3').'</strong></p>';
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). It should work.

Related:

- [WooCommerce add custom email content based on payment method and shipping method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44885575/woocommerce-add-custom-email-content-based-on-payment-method-and-shipping-method/44886437#44886437)
- [How to get WooCommerce order details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39401393/how-to-get-woocommerce-order-details/44708344#44708344)
- [Get orders shipping items details in WooCommerce 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46102428/get-orders-shipping-items-details-in-woocommerce-3/46106700#46106700)